# efficient union of n sorted arrays in C++ (set vs vector)?

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance

I need to implement an efficient algorithm for finding a sorted union from several sorted arrays. Since my program does a lot of these kinds of operation, I simulated it with C++. My first approach (method1) was to simply create an empty vector and append every element in the other vectors to the empty vector then use std::sort and std::unique to obtain the wanted sorted union of all the elements. However, I thought it might be more efficient to dump all the vector elements into a set (method2) because sets will already make them unique and sorted in one go. To my surprise method1 was 5 times faster than method2! Am I doing something wrong here? shouldn't method2 be faster because it does less computations? Thanks in advance

//// method1 with vectors:

```
std::vector<long> arr1{5,12,32,33,34,50};
std::vector<long> arr2{1,2,3,4,5};
std::vector<long> arr3{1,8,9,11};

std::vector<long> arr;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

double sec;
clock_t t;
t=clock();
for(long j=0; j<1000000; j++){ // repeating for benchmark
    arr.clear();
    for(long i=0; i<arr1.size(); i++){
        arr.push_back(arr1[i]);
    }
    for(long i=0; i<arr2.size(); i++){
        arr.push_back(arr2[i]);
    }
    for(long i=0; i<arr3.size(); i++){
        arr.push_back(arr3[i]);
    }
    std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());
    auto last = std::unique(arr.begin(), arr.end());
    arr.erase(last, arr.end());
}
t=clock() - t;
sec = (double)t/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
std::cout<<"seconds = "<< sec <<" clicks = " << t << std::endl;

return 0;
}
```

//// method2 with sets:

```
std::vector<long> arr1{5,12,32,33,34,50};
std::vector<long> arr2{1,2,3,4,5};
std::vector<long> arr3{1,8,9,11};

std::set<long> arr;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

double sec;
clock_t t;
t=clock();
for(long j=0; j<1000000; j++){ //repeating for benchmark
    arr.clear();
    arr.insert(arr1.begin(), arr1.end());
    arr.insert(arr2.begin(), arr2.end());
    arr.insert(arr3.begin(), arr3.end());
}
t=clock() - t;
sec = (double)t/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
std::cout<<"seconds = "<< sec <<" clicks = " << t << std::endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the arrays are sorted, why not merge them and skip identical values immediately while merging, instead of filtering them out afterwards?

Comment: Can we merge them and keep the union sorted? I fail to think about that. Could you please elaborate more? thanks

Comment: Use a read index in each array; always take the smallest of the three elements first; skip any duplicates...

Comment: Additional data structures add some overhead. I'd guess that std::sort is able to take advantage of the fact that the array is already partially sorted. In contrast, inserting into a set in order might lead to an inbalanced tree that needs frequent re-balancing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how it's done with 2 vectors. You can easily generalize the process to N vectors.

```
vector<int> v1{ 4, 8, 12, 16 };
vector<int> v2{ 2, 6, 10, 14 };

vector<int> merged;
merged.reserve(v1.size() + v2.size());

// An iterator on each vector
auto it1 = v1.begin();
auto it2 = v2.begin();

while (it1 != v1.end() && it2 != v2.end())
    {
    // Find the iterator that points to the smallest number.
    // Grab the value.
    // Advance the iterator, and repeat.

    if (*it1 < *it2)
        {
        if (merged.empty() || merged.back() < *it1)
            merged.push_back(*it1);
        ++it1;
        }
    else
        {
        if (merged.empty() || merged.back() < *it2)
            merged.push_back(*it2);
        ++it2;
        }
    }

while(it1 != v1.end())
    {
    merged.push_back(*it1);
    ++it1;
    }

while (it2 != v2.end())
    {
    merged.push_back(*it2);
    ++it2;
    }

// if you print out the values in 'merged', it gives the expected result
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16]
```

...And you can generalize with the following. Note that a helper struct containing both the 'current' iterator and the end iterator would cleaner, but the idea remains the same.

```
vector<int> v1{ 4, 8, 12, 16 };
vector<int> v2{ 2, 6, 10, 14 };
vector<int> v3{ 3, 7, 11, 15 };
vector<int> v4{ 0, 21};

vector<int> merged;
// reserve space accordingly...

using vectorIt = vector<int>::const_iterator;

vector<vectorIt> fwdIterators;
fwdIterators.push_back(v1.begin());
fwdIterators.push_back(v2.begin());
fwdIterators.push_back(v3.begin());
fwdIterators.push_back(v4.begin());
vector<vectorIt> endIterators;
endIterators.push_back(v1.end());
endIterators.push_back(v2.end());
endIterators.push_back(v3.end());
endIterators.push_back(v4.end());

while (!fwdIterators.empty())
    {
    // Find out which iterator carries the smallest value
    size_t index = 0;
    for (size_t i = 1; i < fwdIterators.size(); ++i)
        {
        if (*fwdIterators[i] < *fwdIterators[index])
            index = i;
        }

    if (merged.empty() || merged.back() < *fwdIterators[index])
        merged.push_back(*fwdIterators[index]);

    ++fwdIterators[index];
    if (fwdIterators[index] == endIterators[index])
        {
        fwdIterators.erase(fwdIterators.begin() + index);
        endIterators.erase(endIterators.begin() + index);
        }
    }

// again, merged contains the expected result
[0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 21]
```

...And as some pointed out, using a heap would be even faster

```
// Helper struct to make it more convenient
struct Entry
{
vector<int>::const_iterator fwdIt;
vector<int>::const_iterator endIt;

Entry(vector<int> const& v) : fwdIt(v.begin()), endIt(v.end()) {}
bool IsAlive() const { return fwdIt != endIt; }
bool operator< (Entry const& rhs) const { return *fwdIt > *rhs.fwdIt; }
};


int main()
{
vector<int> v1{ 4, 8, 12, 16 };
vector<int> v2{ 2, 6, 10, 14 };
vector<int> v3{ 3, 7, 11, 15 };
vector<int> v4{ 0, 21};

vector<int> merged;
merged.reserve(v1.size() + v2.size() + v3.size() + v4.size());

std::priority_queue<Entry> queue;
queue.push(Entry(v1));
queue.push(Entry(v2));
queue.push(Entry(v3));
queue.push(Entry(v4));

while (!queue.empty())
    {
    Entry tmp = queue.top();
    queue.pop();

    if (merged.empty() || merged.back() < *tmp.fwdIt)
        merged.push_back(*tmp.fwdIt);

    tmp.fwdIt++;

    if (tmp.IsAlive())
        queue.push(tmp);
    }
```

It does seem like a lot of copying of the 'Entry' object though, maybe a pointer to an entry with a proper comparison function would have been better for the *std::priority_queue*.

Comment: You're not skipping duplicates.

Comment: It's not exactly "easy." Finding the least to merge next among n lists is O(n) unless you use a heap/priority queue.

Comment: @m69 fixed. So much for an if statement.

Comment: @Gene haven't dealt with heap/priority queues for years of programming and I'm not dead. consider looking at the updated answer.

Comment: This is just a special case of the "external" variant of merge sort btw.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Use_with_tape_drives

Comment: @AlexG Thanks a lot for your answer. I tested your code and it is faster than my method2. However, it is still twice slower than method1 !!! I cann't figure out why! Could it be because there is some costy hidden operation in your code?. I'll double check again if I have done the benchmark right.

Comment: Why not to use `std::merge()` ?

Comment: The difference might stem from additional allocations as the result vector grows. Perhaps use reserve() to avoid this?

Comment: @Slava std::merge() is only for 2 vectors! I don't know if it can be more performant to merge many vector pairs.

Comment: @StefanHaustein if I use reserve() in both cases method1 still seems to be faster twice on my machine!

Comment: I'd use larger test vectors. For small sizes, some random overhead might dominate the results.

Comment: @StefanHaustein indeed the vector sizes did matter. I noticed that for vector sizes <100 the naive method1 is much faster than this answer. However, for vector size >100 they seem to converge to the same speed.

Comment: Your method of finding the iterator with the smallest item is O(k), where `k` is the number of iterators. Using a priority queue, it will be O(log k). That reduces the complexity of the merge from O(n * k) to O(n * log(k)). When I benchmarked this a few years back, the difference in running time with just 4 lists was almost 50% (i.e. the priority queue version took just a little more than half the time required by the sequential version). With 10 lists, the difference is huge. And with [stl::priority_queue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue), it's easy to implement.

Comment: @JimMischel thanks for the tip, I updated my answer. Is there any queue variant that 'pops' the object by returning it instead of having to copy from top(), then doing pop() ?

Answer (score 3):

The usual way to merge many queues is to put the queues in a min heap based on the value of their first elements.  The you repeatedly pull an item from the queue on the top of the heap and then push it down to restore the heap property.

This merges a total of N items K queues in O(N log K) time.

Since you are merging `vector<int>`, your queues could be either `tuple<int, vector *>` (current position and vector) or `tuple<vector::const_iterator, vector::const_iterator>` (current position and end)